# username update via API in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

Im going to update the username of an account via the keycloak user update REST API. But it is unable to update it by requesting with the own token. Do I have any other way to get username update by the same user.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Steps:

1. Assign manage-users role myself
2. get my access token
3. get user list - remember my user id
4. add new use with new user name
5. delete my user with #3 user id

1 Assign manage-users role myself
[image]

3 get user list - remember my user id
[image]

4 add new use with new user name
[image]

5 delete my user with #3 user id
[image]

#### Update

From @AlekseyBudaev feedback, why not update via this [PUT API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/22.0.1/rest-api/index.html).
That way is best way instead of remove 'username' and create 'username'

```
PUT /{realm}/users/{id}
```

Body in PUT

```
{
    "username": "<new user name>",
    "firstName": "<new first name>",
    "lastName": "<new last name>",
    "email": "<new e-mail address>"
}
```

[image]

It should enable the `Edit username` in UI
[image]

Before Update
[image]

Change username
[image]

After Update
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Im creating the user via the keycloak admin GUI register option. Is it possible to configure keycloak to assign manage-users role when user register from there?

Comment: It is possible to update via the Rest end points look here -> https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource
It explains the payload you would need to pass for the update operation

Comment: Yes, after registry new user, go new user's "Role Mappings" tab and select "ream-management" at "Client Roles" section then add a "manage-users" roles to Assigned Roles by clicking Add selected button as same as my First attached image.

Comment: @BenchVue is not updating the user, but creating the user.

Comment: @AlekseyBudaev, you have to create a new one and delete the previous, no way to update the user.

Comment: @BenchVue wrong. 1. Enable Edit username in Realm settings -> Login 2. Call `PUT /{realm}/users/{id}. See doc: keycloak.org/docs-api/12.0/rest-api/#_users_resource.

Comment: @AlekseyBudaev, I can find 'PUT /{realm}/users/{id}` API, I can see only 'PUT /{realm}/users/{id}/reset-password'. Can you point out the update username API link?

Comment: @BenchVue, https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html#_updateuser

Comment: @AlekseyBudaev, I tested it by `PUT /{realm}/users/{id}` with `username`  in JSON body, It returned 204 No Content without error but the username did not change.  Other attribute like "firstName", "lastName" and "email" can update. So my conclusion is still No way.

Comment: @BenchVue I said earlier, you need enable 'Edit username' in realm settings. Look in screenshot https://ibb.co/6X19pB3

Comment: @AlekseyBudaev  You are right, It works, I did not know Thanks, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

As Aleksey Budaev mentioned in a comment below the answer, if you already use a PUT request via the API (or want to do it in the GUI), the important part is that you **enable "Edit username" in the Realm settings**! Else the PUT request will ignore this field and still return a 200 response, despite not changing the username!

https://ibb.co/6X19pB3