# which API should use to get user permissions list by userId with Keycloak Admin REST API?

Tags: keycloak

I want get a permissions list of the user, but did't find the method in [keycloak-nodejs-admin-client](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-admin-client) and the API in [Keycloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.1/rest-api/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User needs to assign the **view-users** role to user.

API

```
POST {Keycloak URL:PORT}/auth/admin/realms/{my-realm}/users/{user-ID}/role-mappings/clients/{realm-management-ID}
```

You can do it by Keycloak UI
[image]

After assign this role into user, she can get the user list
Demo by Postman
[image]

If user has no this role, he can't get the user list.
He get the HTTP **403 Forbidden** response status
[image]

In the Keycloak Admin API section,
[Add client-level roles to the user role mapping](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/18.0/rest-api/) but it is not detail information.
[image]

You can see detail steps, how to assign token variable in Postman.
[first step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73570093/keycloak-v-18-how-to-manipulate-with-users-using-keycloak-api/73577215#73577215) in here.
that link use master-token but I use user-token.
It is test{my-realm}'s specific user's(user name is user) token for demo.

If you use the master admin token, can get any realm's user list.

---

#### Update with Keycloak v21.1.1

Run Keycloak by Docker

```
docker run --name mykeycloak -p 8080:8080 \
-e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin \
quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.1.1 \
start-dev
```

##### API

```
POST {Keycloak URL:PORT}/admin/realms/{my-realm}/users/{user-ID}/role-mappings/clients/{realm-management-ID}
```

##### UI

[image]

[image]

Get User Token BY Postman
[image]

[image]

#### Get User list

[image]

Comment: Any idea for Keycloak 21 how this can be configured?

Comment: @PeterPenzov, I updated with Keycloak 2.1.1

Comment: Thanks, I tried the configuration but one thing is not clear: I created the configuration following the steps using `Client` but looks like your config is for User. What payload I need to send with Postman in order above configuration to work?

Comment: @PeterPenzov, I think you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73721142/when-creating-a-new-user-set-realmroles-keycloak-admin-rest-api/73724620#73724620).

Comment: Thanks, one more question do you know for user update what should be the proper payload for PUT request?

Comment: @PeterPenzov, you can update a user in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72488960/username-update-via-api-in-keycloak/72489590#72489590), don't forget to vote me for each answer.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? I need to configure user login to use OTP password after submitting username and password: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76244039/send-verification-code-via-e-mail-after-keycloak-login) Is this possible using the Rest API?

Comment: @PeterPenzov, Thanks for your vote me. Sorry, I have no experience OTP password by API.