# Can't create a user in keycloak via api

Tags: keycloak-admin-client

I'm trying to create user via KeycloakAdminClientService.
Client is confidential and has user creation roles associated.
not able to create the user, I'm getting forbidden 403
below is the code

> UsersResource usersResource = kcProvider.getInstance().realm(realm).users();
> CredentialRepresentation credentialRepresentation = createPasswordCredentials(user.getPassword());

```
    UserRepresentation kcUser = new UserRepresentation();
    kcUser.setUsername(user.getEmail());
    kcUser.setCredentials(Collections.singletonList(credentialRepresentation));
    kcUser.setFirstName(user.getFirstname());
    kcUser.setLastName(user.getLastname());
    kcUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    kcUser.setEnabled(true);
    kcUser.setEmailVerified(false);
    usersResource.create(kcUser);
```

I can fetch the token btw

Comment: User needs to assign "manage_users" realm role. if not will get 403 error.
[This is "view_users" role example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73606410/which-api-should-use-to-get-user-permissions-list-by-userid-with-keycloak-admin/73607156#73607156)

Comment: I've already done that. I've found the solutin. I need to disable csrf in SecurityConfig.configure() by adding
http.csrf().disable();