# How to set an accessToken in postman by passing the credentials in newman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase, postman-newman

I have a pre-request Script in my postmancollections.json file which does the following:

```
const executedOnce = pm.environment.get('executedOnce');
if(executedOnce == 0)
{
    console.log("Getting Access Token");
    const tokenUrl = pm.environment.get('tokenUrl');
    const webApiClientId = pm.environment.get('webApiClientId');
    const scope = pm.environment.get('scope');
    const username = pm.environment.get('username'); 
    const password = pm.environment.get('password');  

    const getTokenRequest = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: tokenUrl,
        body: {
            mode: 'formdata',
            formdata:[
                {key: 'client_id', value: webApiClientId},
                {key: 'scope', value: scope},
                {key: 'grant_type', value: 'password'}, 
                {key: 'username', value: username},
                {key: 'password', value: password}
            ]
        }
    };

    pm.sendRequest(getTokenRequest, (err, response) => {
        const jsonResponse = response.json();
        const newAccessToken = jsonResponse.access_token;
        pm.environment.set('accessToken', newAccessToken);
        pm.environment.set('executedOnce', 1)
        console.log("Access Token Obtained");
    });
```

From my newman, I pass the username and password which are my environment variables. The access Token is getting generated, but is not getting set to the environment variable, because of which my test scripts in collection is failing.

How to update the environment variable accessToken which is dynamically generated after passing username and password in newman?

Some answers suggest an export command at the end of newman run like below:

```
newman run testscripts_postman.json -e localenvironment.json --env-var "username=ABC" --env-var "password=abc" --export-environment localenvironment.json
```

But how will this run in Azure DevOps pipeline if I add an export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`pm.variables()`](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/#using-variables) all other varaibles and `pm.environment()` for `password` and `username`.

it use to define a local variable within a collection. Newman can using it without environmental variables handling.

[image]

[image]

Demo
I will use Keycloak v19(docker image is `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:legacy`) for getting an access token
Then call to get user list with that token.

In `Pre-request Script` tab

```js
const executedOnce = pm.variables.get('executedOnce');
console.log('executedOnce: ' + executedOnce);
if(executedOnce == 0)
{
    console.log("Getting Access Token");
    const tokenUrl = pm.variables.get('tokenUrl');
    const webApiClientId = pm.variables.get('webApiClientId');
    const scope = pm.variables.get('scope');
    const username = pm.environment.get('username'); 
    const password = pm.environment.get('password'); 
    console.log("tokenUrl: " + tokenUrl);

    const getTokenRequest = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: tokenUrl,
        body: {
            mode: 'urlencoded',
            urlencoded:[
                {key: 'client_id', value: webApiClientId},
                {key: 'scope', value: scope},
                {key: 'grant_type', value: 'password'}, 
                {key: 'username', value: username},
                {key: 'password', value: password}
            ]
        }
    };

    pm.sendRequest(getTokenRequest, (err, response) => {
        const jsonResponse = response.json();
        const newAccessToken = jsonResponse.access_token;
        pm.variables.set('accessToken', newAccessToken);
        pm.variables.set('executedOnce', 1)
        console.log("Access Token Obtained");
    });
}
```

[image]

**Note, Keycloak needs `mode: 'urlencoded'`**
If your POST body mode is `formdata`, to use it.

In `Authorization` tab
[image]

In `Test` tab

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log("first user", jsonData[0]);
```

[image]

Test run in Postman
[image]

Export collection (JSON) and environment variables(JSON)

[image]

[image]

Run by `newman` from terminal

```
 newman run 1-demo.postman_collection.json  -e demo.postman_environment.json
```

[image]
*Note, normally get token by `Tests` tab instead `Pre-request Script` tab in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73606410/which-api-should-use-to-get-user-permissions-list-by-userid-with-keycloak-admin/73607156#73607156)

It is more easy due to just get token by separate API then all other API using it.

Comment: If I add it as a collection variable I cannot pass the values in the newman. Only global and environment variables can be passed in newman

Comment: The `getTokenRequest()` get the access token and assign to `accessToken` variable then access by {{accessToken}}. All of step inside newman. This demo shows step without global and environment variables. Why you need to pass an access token to newman?

Comment: I want to pass username and password in newman

Comment: OK, I changed my answer, the `password` and `username` pass from environment variable and all others variables are using variables.

Comment: Thanks. Adding it in environment worked